# How to return the row with the highest sum of two columns?

Tags: sql

I'm making a program that automatically suggests which player to pick based on who has the highest sum of two attribute scores, for example, goals scored & goals saved. As such I have a table (players) that looks something like this:

```
+---------------+--------------+-------------+
|     Name      | GoalsScored  | GoalsSaved  |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+
| John Smith    |           15 |          12 |
| John Doe      |           12 |          20 |
| Bob John      |            7 |           6 |
| John Bob      |           10 |          30 |
| Bobby Johnson |           25 |          30 |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+
```

And a temporary table to store the names of already chosen players (taken_players), which looks something like this:

```
+-----------------+
| takenplayername |
+-----------------+
| Bob John        |
| Bobby Johnson   |
+-----------------+
```

I'm looking for the SQL query that returns the name of the player with the highest GoalsScored + GoalsSaved, as long is that player is not listed in the table of taken players.

```
SELECT * FROM players 
LEFT JOIN taken_players ON players.Name = taken_players.takenplayername 
WHERE taken_players.takenplayername IS NULL 
  AND GoalsScored, GoalsSaved in (
        SELECT MAX(GoalsScored + GoalsSaved) 
        FROM players
  )
```

So far I have the above code, which only partially works. The problems I'm experiencing are that the

```
GoalsScored, GoalsSaved in (SELECT MAX(GoalsScored + GoalsSaved)
```

part of the statement doesn't do what I need it to, I've just guessed at some code here to illustrate what I would like it to do for the purpose of this quesion.

The other problem is that, if the best player is added to the taken players list, the query returns nothing instead of the next best player.

I'm fairly new to this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You want `order by` and something to limit to one row:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM players p LEFT JOIN
     taken_players tp
     ON p.Name = tp.takenplayername
WHERE tp.takenplayername IS NULL
ORDER BY (GoalsScored + GoalsSaved) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The `LIMIT 1` could be several other things depending on the database:

- `SELECT TOP 1`
- `WHERE rownum = 1`
- `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`

Comment: what if two players are tied for the top score?

Comment: @devlincarnate . . . Then one of them would be returned.  The question is specifically in the singular:  "[return] the name of the player with the highest GoalsScored + GoalsSaved", so your question is more appropriate for the OP.

Comment: got it, but perhaps the OP didn't consider the case of a tie, and it's good to clarify a potential problem with the logic, no?

Comment: Also in the case of my data, there is an extremely low chance of a tie top score, there are actually 15 different categories being added together, each with large decimal values.

Comment: @devlincarnate, FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES may help, if your dbms supports it.

Comment: @Jalh . . . In addition, `TOP` in MS Access returns ties and `TOP WITH TIES` in older versions of SQL Server returns ties.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your WHERE clause.  It will select the max sum, but it isn't tied to a specific player.  One way around this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM players p  
LEFT JOIN taken_players t ON p.Name = t.takenplayername 
WHERE t.takenplayername IS NULL
AND (p.GoalsScored + p.GoalsSaved)  = (SELECT MAX(GoalsScored + GoalsSaved) as MaxScore FROM players)
```

NOTE:  this query will return more than one record, in the case when more than one player has the top score (in case of a tie)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from players p where p.id not in (SELECT id from taken_players) and (p.GoalsScored + p.GoalsSaved) = (SELECT MAX(GoalsScored + GoalsSaved) as MaxScore FROM players)
```

Similar to the above answer in that it can potentially give you more than one player. The syntax for getting only one player will vary by DBMS, but this should work in most.

```
SELECT * FROM Players where id = (SELECT MIN(id) from players where players.id NOT in (SELECT id from taken_players) and players.GoalsScored+ players.GoalsSaved = (SELECT MAX(players.GoalsScored+ players.GoalsSaved from players where players.id not in (SELECT id from taken_players))
```